# Must the ground wire be continuous from the panel box, through the meter to the grounding rod?

Tags: electrical, ground

Splitting service to a new power meter. I just cut the wires coming out of the meter box and now the grounding cable is 2' short of the grounding rod.  Must the ground wire be continuous from the panel box, through the meter to the grounding rod?

Comment: I believe an irreversable splice (*e.g.* Cadweld) is OK, but I'll leave the definitive answer to one of the folks who do this for a living.

Comment: Who is your power utility? Also, are your meter and panel in the same box (a meter-main or CSED), or in two separate boxes?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Answer (score 2):

In most circumstances it isn't necessary (or advisable) to go "through the meter", but your exact installation would need to be addressed. The wire should be continuous.

**NEC 250.64 Grounding Electrode Conductor Installation (C) Continuous**...shall be continuous...If necessary, splices shall be...(1)..irreversible compression-type connectors listed as grounding and bonding equipment or by the exothermic welding process.